# MongoDb drops connection after being idle for about 15 minutes

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a Node.js application which connects once (to a remote db) on application start and uses that connection variable for all operations.

```
MongoClient.connect(mongoConnStr, connOpts, function(err, db) {
    ...
}
```

The `connOpts` is:

```
var connOpts = {
    server: { 
        socketOptions: {
            autoReconnect: true, 
            keepAlive: 1 
        }
    }
};
```

So it connects well, but on request after being idle for about ~15mins, it hangs for ~30secs and then throws following error:

```
/home/me/Desktop/turbo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:97
    process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
                                        ^
MongoError: server myapp.cloudapp.net:27017 sockets closed
    at null.<anonymous> (/home/me/Desktop/turbo/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:301:47)
    at g (events.js:199:16)
    at emit (events.js:110:17)
    at null.<anonymous> (/home/me/Desktop/turbo/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:101:12)
    at g (events.js:199:16)
    at emit (events.js:110:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/me/Desktop/turbo/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:139:12)
    at Socket.g (events.js:199:16)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at TCP.close (net.js:485:12)
```

I know that periodically pinging the db should resolve the problem, but maybe some configuration tweaks that I'm missing will do it?

Comment: Does your mongodb-server have firewall or router like nginx?

Comment: Yes, there is a machine with nginx doing reverse proxying, and there is another machine hosting MongoDb that has a firewall.

Comment: actually both of them have firewalls

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
    options: {
        server:{
            auto_reconnect: true,
            socketOptions:{
                connectTimeoutMS:3600000,
                keepAlive:3600000,
                socketTimeoutMS:3600000
            }
        }
    }
```

I have found the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13980236/does-mongodb-have-reconnect-issues-or-am-i-doing-it-wrong).